# How to get the google groups data from google api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-groups-api

How to get the google groups data from google api.
In my Project I need to fetch the google contacts from the specific group(of contacts) and also I need to fetch the google groups for particular or specific User.
Here my problem is I'm not give the username and password for login process.Here i'm using OAUTH Process.

Answer (score 0):

Well Google does explain a bit in relevance to their provisioning API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/groups-settings/.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the documentation is anything but complete. For example, the Google_Service_Groupssettings_Groups_Resource constructor requires four parameters, but the documentation of them is:

"The "groups" collection of methods. Typical usage is: $groupssettingsService = new Google_Service_Groupssettings(...); $groups = $groupssettingsService->groups;" (see [this link](http://fossies.org/dox/moodle-2.8.5/classGoogle__Service__Groupssettings__Groups__Resource.html)).

I don't think that (...) passes for documentation.

The methods are documented in this link: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/, but the code needed to provide access to those methods is well obfuscated.